# Drawing Lines to nearest surface point

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this setup:
[image]

The Wave is a different object than the Curve in the workspace.

I try to draw lines from the control points of the line to the nearest point on the
Wave with this Geometry Nodes tree.
[image]
but I do not get any output.
The connections to the Curve Line inputs indicate that there is something wrong.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: The position is a field output, whereas the curve line accepts only single vector values.

Comment: Thanks,
so I have to SeparateXYZ / CombineXYZ this first?

Comment: nope, this doesn't work OTOH the Start and End are due to the manual the Positions of the Start and End Points of the Curve

Comment: A field value (extremely oversimplified) is something like a group of values. So you will never be able to input them into that socket

Comment: Thanks for the hint - it seems I'll have to Gooooogle a bit how to get the Vector out of the field in this case

Comment: Yepp, with 2 CombineXYZ nodes used to feed a Mesh Line node there will be output.
It seems we have to raise another topic: How to get the Position Vector from the Position?

Comment: What is the difference to your other post? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297884/obtain-vector-of-points-in-geomerty-nodes

Comment: none, but asking differently brought me a usable answer ;)