# Obtain Vector of points in geomerty nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

all answers I have found to this refer to the Transfer Attributes Node but this doesn't exist in Blender 3.6.

What I want to achieve is to draw a Mesh Line between a control point of a line (using the Position Node) and the nearest point of another object using the Geometry Proximity Node.

Connecting the Position output of the Position Node nor the Geometry Proximity Node to the Start and End inputs of the Mesh Line Node doesn't work.

Connecting the Output of 2 Combine XYZ Nodes which I set manually to the inputs of the Mesh Line Node works tough.

How can I convert the Output of the Position Node and of the Geometry Proximity Node to position vectors?

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276087/where-is-transfer-attribute-in-3-4

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that:

[image: node setup]

[image]

Create a *Mesh Line* with 2 points.

Set the position of the first point of this line to the position of the control point. By defining the index value of the *Sample Index* node, you may chose, which control point should be used.

Set the position of the second point of this line to the closest position of the target object by using the *Geometry Proximity* node.

[image: from top]

[image: from iso]

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks :) 
As I already guessed: The Start and End inputs of the Mesh Line / Curve seem to be quite unusable in such a situation. 
Plus your answer gave me a use case for the Sample Index Node to make an example :)